# exponential of a product of any two matrices commuting with one of the matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to show that for any arbitrary matrices A and B,

$e^{AB}A  = Ae^{BA}$

I checked this [other answered question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81386/does-the-exponential-of-a-matrix-commute-with-the-matrix), but this case differs as I have a product of matrices as opposed to a scalar.

Does this apply for any matrices A, and B? Or do they need to commute? (that'd make it easier but it's not specified in the proof I'm trying to solve.)

$$e^{AB} A = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A^nB^n}{n!} A$$
$$e^{AB} A = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A^nB^nA}{n!} $$

Am I missing something obvious? I can't get to $Ae^{BA}$ without commuting A and B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$e^{AB}A=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(AB)^n}{n!}A$, and 
$(AB)^nA=(AB)(AB)\ldots(AB)A=A(BA)(BA)\ldots(BA)=A(BA)^n$, we get 
$e^{AB}A=\sum A\dfrac{(BA)^n}{n!}=Ae^{BA}$.

Comment: Aha! I get it. So we're using the associative property of the product of matrices instead of commuting anything. I can't believe I didn't see it. Thank you very much.